# SharePoint Edition

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

I want to Detect the installed SKU of SharePoint to get the current edition (not the version) using powershell.

I tried , `(Get-SPFarm).Products` it display only a Guid numbers!.

Any help/link would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the below **SharePoint 2016 SKU ID**

- `5DB351B8-C548-4C3C-BFD1-82308C9A519B`, **SharePoint Edition is SharePoint 2016 Trail.**
- `4F593424-7178-467A-B612-D02D85C56940`, **SharePoint Edition is SharePoint 2016 Standard.**
- `716578D2-2029-4FF2-8053-637391A7E683`, **SharePoint Edition is SharePoint 2016 Enterprise.**

**For more details check**

- [PowerShell Script to Detect the Installed SharePoint 2016 Edition](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Script-to-52956bf7)
- [Detect SharePoint 2016 Edition Solution.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40031.sharepoint-2016-detect-the-installed-edition-with-powershell.aspx)
- [PowerShell Script to Detect the Installed SharePoint Edition 2016/2013/2010.](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Script-to-43d93449)
- [SharePoint 2016: Detect SharePoint Edition Using SSOM C#.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40037.sharepoint-2016-detect-sharepoint-edition-using-ssom-c.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | ?{$_.Name -match 'SharePoint'}
```

Adjust to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the above script on two diff farm both list the SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint Server but it didn't show the Edition like enterprise or standard , I want to know "Is the installed SharePoint server is enterprise or standard ?"

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the PowerShell cmdlet provided [here](https://bramdejager.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/how-to-detect-the-installed-sku-of-sharepoint-with-powershell/) to get the installed SKU  and edition information of the installed SharePoint version. It internally uses $((Get-SPFarm).BuildVersion) to get the SKU and finally maps it to the SP Edition which is printed as the Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks I checked this script before, it's SP2010 ! I want to Detect the installed SKU of SharePoint 2016?!